# R: Numerical integration returns a wrong result for a smooth function but does not fail completely

Tags: r, precision, numeric, numerical-methods, integral

I got a very unlikely, but a very dangerous numerical error while integrating thousands of sufficiently well-behaved functions in **R** using the built-in `integrate` function.

*Story (can be skipped).* My problem is connected with maximum likelihood and is based on a highly non-linear function (of 10–20 parameters) for which the analytical expression does not exist, so it requires computing thousands of integrals for one evaluation. I have produced the MWE that contained this error. For the optimisation of this function, due to multiple local optima, I am trying 1000 points for 1000 iterations (with derivative-free methods like particle swarm from `hydroPSO` and differential evolution from `DEoptim`), so just for one model, I have to compute more than a billion integrals (!), and there are 200 candidate models, each of which requires later hot-start reëstimation, so the total number of integrals is way over trillion. I would like to find the fastest solution that gives sufficient accuracy.

The function is a product of two density functions (gamma or similar) times some positive expression, and the joint density is being computed according to the formula `f_{X+Y}(z) = int_{supp Y} f_{X+Y}(z-y, y) dy`. I cannot use convolution because `X` and `Y` are not independent in the general case. The support of `Y` in my case is `(-Inf, 0]`. The scale parameter of the distribution is very small (the model is GARCH-like), so very often, the standard integration routine would fail to integrate a function that is non-zero on a very small section of the negative line (like `[-0.02, -0.01]` where it takes huge values and `0` everywhere else where it is trying hard to compute the quadrature), and R’s `integrate` would often return the machine epsilon because is could not find points in that range where the function took values much greater than zero. In order to combat this problem, I stretch the function around the zero by an inverse of the scale parameter, compute the integral, and then divide it by the scale, i. e. `integrate(f(x/scale)/scale$value)`. However, sometimes, this re-scaling also failed, so I implemented a safety check to see if the value of the scaled function is suspiciously low (i. e. `<1e-8`), and then recompute the integral. The rescaled function was working like a charm, returning nice values where the non-scaled one failed, and in the rare cases the rescaled function returned a machine epsilon, the non-rescaled one worked.

**Until today when integration of the rescaled function suddenly yielded a value of 1.5 instead of 3.5.** Of course the function passed the safety check (because this is a plausible value, not machine epsilon, and some other values were less than this, so it was in the common range). It turned out, roughly in 0.1% of all cases, `integrate` under-estimated the function. The MWE is below.

First, we define the function of `x` and an optional parameter `numstab` that defines the scaling.

```
cons <- -0.020374721416129591
sc <- 0.00271245601724757383
sh <- 5.704
f <- function(x, numstab = 1) dgamma(cons - x * numstab, shape = sh, scale = sc) * dgamma(-x * numstab, shape = sh, scale = sc) * numstab
```

Next, we plot it to make sure that the scaling works correctly.

```
curve(f, -0.06, 0, n = 501, main = "Unscaled f", bty = "n")
curve(f(x, sc), -0.06 / sc, 0, n = 501, main = "Scaled f", bty = "n")
```

[image: Unscaled function for integration][image: Scaled function for integration]

And then we check this integral by summation:

```
sum(f(seq(-0.08, 0, 1e-6))) * 1e-6 # True value, 3.575294
sum(f(seq(-30, 0, 1e-4), numstab = sc)) * 1e-4 # True value, 3.575294
str(integrate(f, -Inf, 0)) # Gives 3.575294
# $ value       : num 3.58
# $ abs.error   : num 1.71e-06
# $ subdivisions: int 10
str(integrate(f, -Inf, 0, numstab = sc))
# $ value       : num 1.5 # WTF?!
# $ abs.error   : num 0.000145 # WTF?!
# $ subdivisions: int 2
```

It stop at just two subdivisions! Now, in order to see what is going on during the integration, we create a global object and update it every time the integration routine does something.

```
global.eval.f <- list()
f.trace <- function(x, numstab = 1) {
  this.f <- f(x, numstab)
  global.eval.f[[length(global.eval.f) + 1]] <<- list(x = x, f = this.f)
  return(this.f)
}
integrate(f.trace, -Inf, 0)
```

Now, we visualise this integration process.

```
library(animation)
l <- length(global.eval.f)
mycols <- rainbow(l, end = 0.72, v = 0.8)
saveGIF({
  for (i in 1:l) {
    par(mar = c(4, 4, 2, 0.3))
    plot(xgrid <- seq(-0.1, -0.01, length.out = 301), f(xgrid), type = "l", bty = "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "f(x)", main = "Function without stabilisation")
    for (j in 1:(l2 <- length(this.x <- global.eval.f[[i]]$x))) lines(rep(this.x[j], 2), c(0, global.eval.f[[i]]$f[j]), col = mycols[i], type = "b", pch = 16, cex = 0.6)
    legend("topleft", paste0("Quadrature: ", i), bty = "n")
    text(rep(-0.1, l2), seq(325, 25, length.out = l2), labels = formatC(sort(this.x), format = "e", digits = 2), adj = 0, col = ifelse(sort(this.x) > -0.1 & sort(this.x) < -0.01, mycols[i], "black"), cex = 0.9)
  }
}, movie.name = "stab-off-quad.gif", interval = 1 / 3, ani.width = 400, ani.height = 300)
```

[image: Quadrature without stabilisation]

And the same thing, but on a different scale.

```
global.eval.f <- list()
integrate(f.trace, -Inf, 0, numstab = sc)
l <- length(global.eval.f)
mycols <- rainbow(l, end = 0.7, v = 0.8)
saveGIF({
  for (i in 1:l) {
    par(mar = c(4, 4, 2, 0.3))
    plot(xgrid <- seq(-0.1 / sc, -0.01 / sc, length.out = 301), f(xgrid, sc), type = "l", bty = "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "f(x)", main = "Function with stabilisation")
    for (j in 1:(l2 <- length(this.x <- global.eval.f[[i]]$x))) lines(rep(this.x[j], 2), c(0, global.eval.f[[i]]$f[j]), col = mycols[i], type = "b", pch = 16, cex = 0.6)
    legend("topleft", paste0("Quadrature: ", i), bty = "n")
    text(rep(-0.1 / sc, l2), seq(325 * sc, 25 * sc, length.out = l2), labels = formatC(sort(this.x), format = "e", digits = 2), adj = 0, col = ifelse(sort(this.x) > -0.1 / sc & sort(this.x) < -0.01 / sc, mycols[i], "black"), cex = 0.9)
  }
}, movie.name = "stab-on-quad.gif", interval = 1 / 3, ani.width = 400, ani.height = 300)
```

[image: Quadrature with stabilisation]

The problem is, I cannot try various stabilising multipliers for the function because I have to compute this integral a trillion times, so even in the super-computer cluster, this takes weeks. Besides that, reducing the `rel.tol` just to `1e-5` helped a bit, but I am not sure whether this guarantees success (and reducing it to `1e-7` slowed down the computations in some cases). And I have looked at the Fortran code of the quadrature just to see the integration rule.

The timings can be seen below (I added an extra attempt with a lower tolerance).

[image: Integration timings]

How can I make sure that the integration routine will not produce such wrong results for such a function, and the integration will still be fast?

Comment: Can you determine an approximate bound on the lower limit of integration?  The problem seems to be associated with `-Inf` as the lower limit of integration.

Comment: @thc It is possible, yes, but not very practical. Since the `x` variable represents the distribution of one-sign market returns, we can safely assume that the unscaled function will never take values significantly different from zero below −0.3. However, this model is used to compute the Value-at-Risk (5%, 1%, 0.1%), so tail behaviour is extremely important. In other models, instead of gamma distribution, power law decay is used, and the bound might be wide. Finally, the official `integrate` manual advocates the use of actual `Inf`inite limits instead of just very large values (like -1e1)..?

Comment: You could use a bounded integral to detect when there is an issue, if it differs from the unbounded integral too much.  Two meta-suggestions: 1) you may get better responses on r-devel, as your example does seem sort of bug-lite.  2) You may eventually want to check out other libraries, as R would be slower with that much computation.  E.g.: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/gauss_kronrod.html

Comment: @thc Thank you. To be on the safe side, I shall try three options (unscaled unbounded, scaled unbounded, unscaled bounded), and then and pick the maximum (because it can only under-estimate). I shall also try to use the Boost library and maybe pre-compute more points (with G10—K21 or G15—K31 rule; I shall `microbenchmark` which one converges faster).

Comment: Do you mind if I post this question to r-devel? Would you agree that it's a bug?

Comment: @thc I wrote to r-devel 6 hours ago, but this thing seems to be on moderation. I should be grateful if you either approved it (if you can) or posted it.

Comment: I have no power there, but if its your first post, it requires a moderator to manually approve.  Someone will get to it eventually ^_^